# google places search api and "Listings by" Text

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

i have a problem with the Google Map and the places search API.

Everytime i run a new search Google adds the Text "Listings by blabla" on the map.

If i run multiple Searches, the API adds multiple Elements with this texts on the map.

Look at the lower right corner: http://s14.directupload.net/images/141016/raq2cfah.jpg

How can i remove this layer, so that only one of this elements is on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is  because the Text "Listing by bla bla" is added every time you create a new instance of google.maps.places.PlacesService. To resolve this make sure that only one instance of the PlacesService is created.One solution which worked for me was having a variable store the first time it loads and then call it from next time on.

```js
//Have a local variable
var placesService;

//Method that will be using the search.
performNearbySearch(placesRequest) {

  //Check if the PlacesService is already instantiated else create it. 
  if (!this.placesService) {
    this.placesService = new google.maps.PlacesService(this.gmap);
  }

  //Create a placesRequest
  var request = placesRequest;

  //Call the API.
  this.placesService.nearbySearch(request, < callback Function > , true));
}
```

This way only the first time The "Listing Appears".

Check this for more information https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/sQ-isvqfdBM

Comment: Maybe some code to explain the usage? Or did you just google this?

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry for the late reply. I googled it to get the answer. The issue is each time we do a search a new instance of google.maps.places.PlacesService is created, and the listings appear for each instance that you create.

Comment: @kaushikkumar Im not asking you for your response to me. I'm asking you to improve your answer. It's little more than just a link and as I said already, it very much looks like you just typed in a search and posted this. Of course if you actually know more about it then you can explain it better and give some example code to back up the solution. I think you would find that will likely result in up-votes from people who found that information useful. Just a link however, someone will come across and request it's removal eventually. Your choice.